# 500-Internal server error on saving release template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

I am facing this issue while saving the release template. I have added a new stage in this template, copied another stage to the new one and started editing the values. On saving the template this error is showing, please see the error message  screen below.

[image: 500-Internal server error on saving release template]

Comment: Server logs would have more information. Can you check the server logs and share the error that you can see there.

Comment: Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavi

Comment: This is from windows logs

Comment: Tried a new  release, but it's stuck in in it's first action... :( please help

Comment: other templates are fine